# django - urlshortener app

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write my own urlshortener app in django.

I did so far these things:

model

```
class LinkURL(models.Model):
  url_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  url = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
  clicks = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.url
```

and urls.py

```
url(r'^shorty.u/(?P<urlhash>\w+)$', include('urlshortener.urls')),
```

I thought, my new short url is called `shorty.u` and some `url_hash` is attached so it can find the real url in LinkURL Model. so it would look like `shorty.u/oijioe` for example.

but i am stuck here not knowing how to redirect this `shorty.u` url to real url, does `shorty.u` have to be a registered url? how will `shorty.u` find my server so that I can redirect to real one?

any hints and guidance are appreciated much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your view for `http://www.myhost.com/shorty.u/*` returning an `HttpResponse`, you lookup the redirect address in your DB and return an `HttpResponseRedirect`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects

so `return HttpResponseRedirect("http://www.google.com")` should bounce your user to google.

So your view goes something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def myview(request, params):
  # get the URL from the DB...
  #....
  return HttpResponseRedirect(target_url)
```

Comment: the question is how to come ``shorty.u``. my real url is called ``www.doniyor.de``. if it were ``www.doniyor.de/shorty.u`` then no problem. but it is ``shorty.u`` only. does this make sense?

Comment: You want people to go to `http://shorty.u/abcdefg`? You can't do that unless you own `shorty.u` as a DNS name. And I don't think `.u` is a valid top-level domain name. So you can't do that. It has to have the domain name of the server somewhere...

Comment: yes, exactly. oh ok. this was what I didnot know. I think, for now, I go for ``www.doniyor.de/short/abcdefg``

Comment: so, here comes the "thank you": THANKS :) please edit your answer so it has the answer I wanted and so i can check it ;)